# Use of com_checkin and $canChange and $canCheckin in listview

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, view, acl, layout

I 'm writing a listView's default layout for my component in which I 'm implementing Joomla's publish & unpublished feature in which user can publish an item on single click on check box. 
I am little confused about statement of getting user authentication for $canChange given below:

```
$canCheckin = $user->authorise('core.manage', 'com_checkin') || $item->checked_out == $userId || $item->checked_out == 0;
```

> can any body tell me way we authenticate user against com_checkin.?

secondly I think it is wrong, this should be like following:

```
$canCheckin = $user->authorise('core.manage', 'com_my_component') && $item->checked_out==$user->id || $item->checked_out==0;
```

In the above code I authenticate user against my component to make sure if user authorise for check_in, also I check if the the item is not checked to other user for editing

> now the question is where is am I wrong and if I am right then why
>   com_content authenticate user against com_checkin

Answer (score 1):

`com_checkin` is a special component which allows user to check in all items in all components, clear the cache and purge the expired cache.

So when you authenticate a user against `com_checkin` you are making sure that this user has right to check in this item (if he has `manage` rights then he can check in any items).

Comment: okey sir thanks but i'm still confused what is the benefit of authenticating user against com_checkin though we can do same by authenticating manage authority against  com_my_component.?

Comment: You can do it in your component if you will create a special access rule like `item.checkin` in it. Otherwise you should check this for `com_checkin`.